# Passing an array of Images from JS file to EJS

Tags: javascript, html, ejs, src

Hi I am trying to pass an array of image src's from my javascript file to my ejs file below.

```
 <div id = "flick">

<img src="nothing.jpg" id="image" name="image"/>

 <% var imgArray = imgLinks %>  //Grab the array of img src's
            <script>
              var passArray = [];
              passArray = <%= imgArray  %>; // Pass to a local array 
              for (i = 0; i < passArray.length; i++){

                document.getElementById('image').src = passArray[i];
              }
              </script>

 </div>
```

I have tested and found that i am receiving the array 'imgLinks' correctly , but i would like to know how i could pass and display all the array of images. I am new to Javascript sorry if this is dumb.

Answer (score 0):

You keep overwriting the same image tag with an image until you are at the end of the array.

What you could do is to clone the image tag and then add it as child to the "flick" `div`

```
      var passArray = [];
      passArray = <%= imgArray  %>; // Pass to a local array 
      for (i = 0; i < passArray.length; i++){
        var itm = document.getElementById('image');
        var cpy = itm.cloneNode(true);
        cpy.id = "image" + i;
        cpy.src = passArray[i];
        document.getElementById("flick").appendChild(cpy);
      }
```

This will generate a copy of top most image and append it to the flick `div`. If you need to remove the original `img` tag you can execute:

`document.getElementById("image").remove()`

after the for loop.

See a working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lsh2y1j/2/